# Delete some Theorems without destroying the numbering

Tags: math-mode, numbering, theorems

I wrote some math lecture notes with ongoing numbering of definitions and theorems. Now i want to create a shorter version to use as handout, without proofs, examples.. But if i remove some, the numbering of my handout and my notes aren't equal. Obviously...

Is there a solution to delete some definitions, theorems and examples without changing the numbering, so that the numeration of the remaining content is still the same?

Comment: You can always increase the relevant counter by one.

Comment: thanks to your answer, it works as well. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic solution: surround the statements you want to ignore in the abridged version with `\startignore` and `\stopignore`.

If the line `\abridgedtrue` is commented out, then the document will compile normally; otherwise the theorem to be ignored are typeset in a disposable box; this will increment the counters but print nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newif\ifabridged
%\abridgedtrue % remove the leading % for ignoring theorems

\ifabridged
  \long\def\startignore{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}
  \def\stopignore{\egroup}
\else
  \let\startignore\relax
  \let\stopignore\relax
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is an important definition
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is an important theorem
\end{theorem}

\startignore
\begin{theorem}
This is a not so important theorem
\end{theorem}
\stopignore

\begin{theorem}
This is an important theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is like magic! Many thanks, it works perfectly. :-)